# What is the name of this cable?

Tags: layer1, cable

The cable is plugged on a Zyxel VES1724-56 DSLAM. It is a VDSL cable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJOHZ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdJPH.jpg

Comment: Don't you remember parallel printers? You must be young.

Comment: Google has the manual that will tell you everything you need to know about this unit and what connects to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a good authoritative source, but as per your picture, we also use in our ADSL and VDSL DSLAMs/MSANs.

It is an RJ21 connector, sometimes also called an RJ21X connector.

[This page](http://www.eurovoice.co.uk/index.php/martin-s-blog/53-rj11-rj14-rj21x-rj45-431a) has the more accurate picture I can find. That is how we often use them, pack to a patch panel to break out into RJ11 ports (for testing in the LAB) or back to krone blocks in a live PoP.

[This page](http://ftp.ipsyn.net/pub/mirrrs/cabling/rj21x.html) has a wiring guide.

Comment: Beautiful ! RJ21 is exactly what I was looking for. My cable also break out into RJ11 connectors.

Answer (score 2):

The connector is a Centronics 50 like this:

[image]

You have to look for a cable for 25 pairs male with centronics / amphenol connector like [this](http://www.l-com.com/ethernet-category-3-25-pair-trunk-cables-male-to-male-90-degree-connectors) or [this](http://www.sandman.com/25pair.html):

Answer (score 1):

This is variously called an Amphenol, a Telco 50-way connector, and sometimes (rarely) a Centronics.  In the kinds of places where you find DSLAMs like this unit -- communication service providers-- the term "Amphenol" is what I've heard most.  Basically it is a very convenient form factor for aggregating connections.  In this case, the DSLAM is going to be aggregating multiple connections from end user premises (houses, apartments etc) and so instead of plugging in dozens of individual lines they are aggregated into the Amphenol and connected.

Amphenol was the standard connector used in telcos for aggregating DS1s.  At higher densities other connectors are used, such as coax for DS3.  These days fiber is also used a lot, for even higher densities.